# Visual Network Topology Map?

Tags: network-monitoring

If I have no idea of the current network setup, and I'm connected to the LAN - is there any GUI that could possibly identify nodes visually or give me any sort of insight?

I'm looking for a more comprehensive solution than Window's built in Network Map, which only shows your connection or any systems where you have administrative rights.

This would possibly identify hardware (Repeaters, Access Points, Cameras, Switches, Phones etc...)

Rather than dig into walls using Toners and Cable Testers, I was thinking there could be something out there.

I'm using Windows and Ubuntu.

This was recommended for serverfault, originally posted on superuser. 
[superuser question page](https://superuser.com/questions/4682/visual-network-topology-map)
A 100 point bounty is pending.

Answer (score 8):

Try "[The dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude.php)" - it's free and works... I'd recommend installing it on a VMware machine, as I find it leaves quite a footprint behind.

Mike

Answer (score 5):

On the Windows side, I like [LANsurveyor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/LANsurveyor/) from Solarwinds.

Answer (score 1):

You might find nmaps [Topology](http://nmap.org/book/zenmap-topology.html) tab useful.

Answer (score 1):

3Com network director could help as well - I think it has a 60 day trial before becoming less functional.

Uses SNMP to find, well everything.  Even does nice links showing what is connected to what.

Answer (score 0):

There was an old tool called 'tkined' that would do something like this.  I think it worked by finding default gatewaysn and doing a bunch of digging around via public snmp info to map things out. [This](http://wiki.tcl.tk/691) is the best info I can find on it now, though - it seems to be a bit crufty.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [EtherApe](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/).