# Network Diagramming software options?

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

I've used [The Dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude.php) to map my network, but I can only export the network map as a graphics file. I've also used Dia and Vision to manually diagram portions of my network.

Does anyone out there have a solution where I can do automatic network mapping using a tool like  "The Dude", then pull that file over to a manually editable format for cleaning up and/or enhancing in Visio or Dia?

Comment: this has been asked several times: http://serverfault.com/questions/2163/network-mapping-tools && http://serverfault.com/questions/28085/network-diagramming-software-free-or-open-source && http://serverfault.com/questions/66369/how-to-build-a-network-application-topogrophy && http://serverfault.com/questions/43307/visual-network-topology-map

Comment: I had searched before, but this thread:
http://serverfault.com/questions/66369/how-to-build-a-network-application-topogrophy

actually seemed to help. The rest were just saying use dia, or use the dude, and it's not what I was asking. Thanks for finding this one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nmap can map networks. You can get the output in various ways, xml for example: http://nmap.org/book/man-output.html

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a load of suggestions here:

[What tools can create a map of my network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2163/network-mapping-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Spiceworks is a pretty complete tool

http://www.spiceworks.com/

Comment: But it doesn't do anything the OP wanted, except for generating a Flash network map.  (no exports, etc)

Comment: I thought his main concern was that he was able to edit the network map. And this can be done with spiceworks.

Comment: @ Bob:  From the OP: "Then pull that file over to a manually editable format for cleaning up and/or enhancing in Visio or Dia?"

Comment: Thanks Josh, you seem to get the direction I'm looking for.